# Javascript alert statement with string & int

Tags: javascript

Im a newbie to Javascript and trying to debug a simple js function..I need to get the value of x through the alert statement but it doesn't display correctly..How to concatenate a string and int as in this case..

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function displaydate()  
            {
                document.getElementById("test").innerHTML='first line changed';
                document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML='second line changed';
                var x = 5;
                alert("Value of x" + String.valueOf(x));
            }
        </script>
        <p id="test">this is the 1st line</p>
        <p id="test1">this is the 2nd line</p>
        <button type="button" onclick="displaydate()">clickme!</button>

    <body>
</html>
```

New code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function displaydate()  
            {
                document.getElementById("test").innerHTML='first line changed';
                document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML='second line changed';
                var x = 5;
                alert("Value of x=" + x);
                var cars=new Array();
                cars[0]='car';
                cars[1]='Volvo';
                alert("Value of arrary 1 var=' + cars[0]);
                //alert("Value of arrary 2 var='+cars[1]);
            }
        </script>
        <p id="test">this is the 1st line</p>
        <p id="test1">this is the 2nd line</p>
        <button type="button" onclick="displaydate()">clickme!</button>

    <body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not `alert("Value of x :" + x);` (or better `console.log(x)`) ?

Comment: I guess you come from Java.. `String.valueOf` does something entirely different in Javascript than in Java. In fact pretty much everything that looks like Java signatures work entirely different. In Javascript, any object can define a magical `valueOf` function, which can return a primitive numeric value when that object is used in numeric context.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
alert("Value of x" + x);
```

JavaScript is a dynamic language. The conversion is done automatically for you. When you do something like "var x = string + int"

**Update**

The reason your alert is failing now is because you start the alert with a double quotation mark and end the string piece of the alert with a single quote.

Comment: That worked..but my array is failing similary... Have given the code

Comment: @user1050619 you have syntax error in your string. It can be seen from the syntax highlight.

Answer (score 5):

You can just do:

```
alert("Value of x - " + x);
```

No need to call `valueOf` the conversion will be automatic (implicit).